# How to uncheck a checkbox when another one is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

With Javascript, I would like one first checkbox to get unchecked when I check the second one. I also would like that the two checkboxes can be unchecked after having been checked.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-1" class="radio" /><label for="radio-1">Yes</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-2" class="radio" /><label for="radio-2">No</label>
```

I tried with two checkboxes, but I don't manage to uncheck #1 when #2 is checked.

Here is my Jsfiddle with the example with two checkboxes:
http://jsfiddle.net/3f66j30y/

I also tried with two radio buttons, but I don't manage to remain them unchecked after having been checked.

Comment: Radio buttons require a radio button in a group to be checked, hence you couldn't uncheck both

Comment: "I also would like that the two checkboxes can be unchecked after having been checked." ?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I think he means he want's these 3 possible combinations(`on-off`,`off-on`,`off-off`)

Comment: @NickA alright I see now.

Comment: @NickA sure, I see your updated comment.

Comment: maybe you could add third radio button "-" or "(none)"? and make it selected by default? you know - one line in HTML or >20 in CSS+JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `onclick` event to each checkbox to uncheck the other checkbox

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
display:none;
}
 
input[type="checkbox"] + label
{
padding:10px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:#dedede;
color:black;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
display:inline-block;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label
{
padding:10px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:green;
color:white;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-1" class="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('radio-2').checked = false"/><label for="radio-1">Yes</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-2" class="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('radio-1').checked = false"/><label for="radio-2">No</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also the explanation about the radio buttons.

Comment: @Guillaume no, never put JS in the HTML like this if you can avoid it — it's a maintenance nightmare and more than likely means you're not being DRY

Comment: @mike I would in general agree, but in the case of 2 buttons, I'd argue that this is easily maintainable and you're writing less by not moving it to a function.  As proof, compare the byte count of yours against mine.

Comment: @NickA I'm coming off a sugar rush ;) That "never" was a little extreme (there are times where it may be appropriate on a limited basis), but I think I wanted to hit home that I've seen a lot of poorly managed code that is extremely difficult to maintain.  This is especially true in legacy sites written in ruby, php, perl, or ASP; which have JavaScript embedded in the body.

Comment: @mike absolutely, I would never do this in anything more than, well, this, even 3 or 4 checkboxes I would move it out, but with the 2 in this example, I find it acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The following in a Vanilla JS solution, which:

- binds change events when the DOM is loaded
- only binds one change event to the parent container
- in the change event, decides what the target is and turns off other checkboxes

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.select-group').onchange = changeEventHandler;
}, false);

function changeEventHandler(e) {
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('.cb');
  cbs.forEach(function(cb) {
    if (cb != e.target)
      cb.checked = false;
  });
}
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #dedede;
  color: black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-group">
  <input id="cb_yes" type="checkbox" value="yes" class="cb" />
  <label for="cb_yes">Yes</label>
  <input id="cb_no" type="checkbox" value="no" class="cb" />
  <label for="cb_no">No</label>
</div>
```

It can certainly be improved; after all, one obvious point is that you're searching the DOM for the checkboxes every time they change — you could easily cache them.  However, this should serve a point and show you how easy it is to work with standard JS.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery` to achieve this.

```js
$(".radio").change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(".radio").prop('checked',false);
    if(checked) {
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
display:none;
}
 
input[type="checkbox"] + label
{
padding:10px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:#dedede;
color:black;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
display:inline-block;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label
{
padding:10px 10px;
text-align:center;
background:green;
color:white;
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-1" class="radio" /><label for="radio-1">Yes</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-2" class="radio" /><label for="radio-2">No</label>
```

Comment: You don't think including jQuery is a bit overkill for this?

Answer (score 1):

Behavior you are looking for is specific to radio buttons. However the problem is - you can't uncheck it, once checked. In this case you can use three radio buttons - yes, no and none (-) - since clearly you want more then two options:

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio-0" name="group-one" class="radio" checked /><label for="radio-0">-</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="group-one" class="radio" /><label for="radio-1">Yes</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="group-one" class="radio" /><label for="radio-2">No</label>
```

If you prefer to stick with two, you can use your checkboxes with a bit of JavaScript to switch the opposite box off:

```js
function radioSwitch(opposite) {
    document.getElementById(opposite).checked = false;
}
document.getElementById("radio-1").addEventListener("click",
    function() { radioSwitch("radio-2"); });
document.getElementById("radio-2").addEventListener("click",
    function() { radioSwitch("radio-1"); });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-1" class="radio" /><label for="radio-1">Yes</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="radio-2" class="radio" /><label for="radio-2">No</label>
```